# github, are pull requests auto-generated for bumping up a dependency version always safe?

Tags: github

I have noticed that some MRs get auto created for bumping dependencies like

`Bump axios from 0.18.0 to 0.18.1 in xxx`
`Bump ini from 1.3.5 to 1.3.7 in xxx`

What are these and is it always safe to simply accept the change?

Comment: The PR should include a full explanation of the vulnerability. Other than that, it's as safe as any dependency upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are these?

These are security updates generated by [Dependabot](https://dependabot.com/). It monitors your dependencies for security problems. When it finds one it suggests an upgrade based on recommendations by the developers and security experts.

You can find details about the security issue in your Security tab. This usually includes a link to the [CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/) post about the issue, and the developer's commentary and recommended action.

See [About Dependabot security updates](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-security-vulnerabilities/about-dependabot-security-updates) for more.

> and is it always safe to simply accept the change?

The tl;dr is yes.

The long answer is you have to weigh the security risk vs the risk it could introduce new bugs and incompatibilities, but with the knowledge this has been reviewed by experts and the action recommended by the developers. To mitigate this, Dependabot makes the smallest possible upgrade which resolves the security issue. If you have a solid test suite for your project it should catch any problems caused by the update.

If you're relying on undocumented features, such as [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch), upgrading always has a risk. You can mitigate this by configuring those dependencies to stay within a version range, and by having good tests to ensure the undocumented features continue to work. However, you should minimize your use of undocumented features.

In your case, 0.18.0 to 0.18.1 and 1.3.5 to 1.3.7 indicate they are patch releases which contain only bug fixes to version 0.18.x and 1.3.x respectively. They should be safe. This is [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) adopted by projects to give you a better idea of what changes are in each version.

For example, in one of my projects Dependabot has found a low priority security issue in a dependency that I don't use directly (a dependency of a dependency). The dependency is a very important one for many projects, so I have a lot of trust in their updates. Dependabot did not generate a PR, only a security alert which recommended an upgrade. However, there is not yet a stable release which fixes the problem, only a release candidate, and it is a minor update from 1.1 to 1.2, not just a bug fix release. After reading the security alert I've judged it does not put us at risk. The risks of using a minor update release candidate are greater than a low priority security issue, so I'm waiting for a stable release.

Comment: Thanks! one minor question, can this be turned off as well?

Comment: @BrandonLee Yes, instructions are in the linked Github "About Dependabot security updates"

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if the code is semantically versioned and the version is just a patch version, then generally they're pretty safe.  But there are always risks to bumping versions:

- The new dependency could actually be incompatible in some subtle way and break things.
- The new dependency could contain new bugs that impact the functionality of the program.
- The new code could contain additional security vulnerabilities.

These are the same risks as happen with any new code, so they are not any riskier than introducing other new code.

You may also want to distinguish between bumping versions just because there's a new version and bumping versions because there's a bug or security vulnerability.  The former is a bit hostile to other users of your package, especially if they need to use an older toolchain or environment or your package is a dependency, whereas the latter is generally useful, and in the case of security vulnerabilities, responsible.